# How to add attributes to hard coded images in Drupal 7 themes

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I am using

```
<?php echo theme('image', array('path' => drupal_get_path('theme', 'themename') .'/img/demo.png')); ?>
```

To hard code images into my Drupal 7 theme.  My question is how do I add attributes like "id", "class" or "alt"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add extra attributes, you pass an array `attributes` with the necessary `key => value` pair. Identical for the `alt` attribute.

For example:

```
print theme('image', array(
    'path' => drupal_get_path('theme', 'themename') . '/img/demo.png',
    'alt' => 'my alt content',
    'attributes' => array(
        'id' => 'myId',
        'class' => 'myClass',
    ))
);
```